# micronaut yaml properties list

Tags: yaml, micronaut

I have a list with configurations for producers:

```
myproject:
  process:
    article:
      topic: masterdata.product
      detail:
    supplier:
      topic: masterdata.supplier
      detail:
    others:
      topic: masterdata.others
      detail:
```

is it possible to inject all topics properties into a value?

something like this

```
@Value("${myproject.process.*.topic}")
```

Regards

Comment: "is it possible to inject all topics properties into a value?" - Yes, but not with `@Value("${myproject.process.*.topic}")`.  The question title mentions a list.  Are you wanting to inject these values into a list?  The YAML currently doesn't contain a list but can be reorganized to support that.

Comment: The yaml is used in another part of the code but I need to extract the list of the topics for testing. is it posible?

Comment: Given the config data shown in the question, do you want a `List` of `Map` injected somewhere such that there are 3 `Map` in the `List`, and each of those `Map` have the keys `topic` and `detail`, the value of `detail` is `null` in all cases and the values of `topic` are what is shown in the config?

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be to define an extra object:

```java
@EachProperty(“myproject.process”)
class Process {
   String topic;
   // …
}

// then inject and collect all topics:

@Inject
List<Process> processes;
```